# Python xml.etree.ElementTree directory acess

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ID="000296166"
tree = ET.parse("\folder" + ID +'.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

What I'm trying to do is access XML files that aren't in the same folder as the `.py` using the function from `xml.etree.elementtree`

It keeps giving the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '\x0colder000296166.xml'
```

I keep getting the feeling that I did something wrong when writing the path...but I can't find any examples online to see how it's supposed to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\f` is interpreted as the page brake and is replaced with hex code `0xC`. You should remove leading backslash from path.

```
tree = ET.parse("folder" + ID +'.xml')
```

And if you use backslash inside strings it can be escaped like this `\\`

**EDIT**

When you work with paths it is better to use os.path module:

```
 import os 
 ...
 tree = ET.parse(os.path.join('folder', ID + '.xml'))
```

Comment: thx man! the "\\" is what was missing...but just to correct myself too: it was "folder\\" and not "\folder"...the backlashes needed to be between the strings to acess the folder

Comment: In this case it is better to use os.path module. You can check an edit for details.