# How to handle path name with backslash followed by numbers?

Tags: python, xml, path, elementtree

I'm writing a Python script where a file path is returned as a string. The file path is something like `C:\user\test\2016\1005\text.xml`. When I tried to give this string to `ET.parse()`, it incorrectly treats the `\20` and `\10` portion of the path as special characters, and so the parsing fails.

How can I handle such situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to escape the backslashes in the strings:

```
ET.parse("C:\\some\\path.xml")
```

or via

```
ET.parse(r"C:\some\path.xml")
```

and I would recommend to use the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module:

```
import os
ET.parse(os.path("C:\\some\\path.xml")
```

Other threads with similar problems: [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351127/python-xml-etree-elementtree-directory-acess).